# Child nav item only showing up on parent page in nav menu when using Structure

Tags: structure, navigation, parent, child

I have the following menu built with Structure:

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/" include_ul="no" exclude="10|11|12|13"}
{/exp:structure:nav}
```

One of my pages is called "About" and a child page called "Our Team."

The problem is that "Our Team" only shows up in navigation when on the "About" or "Our Team" pages.  If I navigate to another page like "Services," the 2nd level navigation disappears.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add show_depth="2" to the nav tag to reveal all children on the second level. Also, remove the end tag, it's not a wrapper.